# Validation of same date of birth in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

How can I compare same date of births in GWT using `Date`?

```
olpPatient.getBirthday().equals(birthday);
```

Even if both dates are equal, that line returns false.

Comment: Please clarify what kind of `Date` you are using. If you're using `java.util.Date`, you can use [`Date#compareTo(Date)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo(java.util.Date)).

Comment: Who is trying to close this question??? This is a good question.

Comment: @Baz: GWT translates it into JavaScript. JavaScript used to have some quirks when comparing dates. I don't know if it was ever fixed.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin I'm well aware that it's translated to JavaScript. From what I can tell, both `equals` and `compareTo` work just fine. Just tested it with two `Date` objects created using the same time stamp. That's why the OP has to elaborate.

Comment: @Baz - You are right. GWT had an issue, but it was fixed in 2011.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the class `com.google.gwt.user.datepicker.client.CalendarUtil`. There is a method called [`isSameDate(Date, Date)`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/datepicker/client/CalendarUtil.html) which will just check the date, not the time of day.

From the javadoc:

> Check if two dates represent the same date of the same year, even if they have different times.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing `Date` objects by using `equals()` (by default, `Object.equals` is checking whether references to these objects are equal or not and `Date.equals` checking timestamps). But you need only to exract `day`, `month`, `year` from those objects and compare only them.

Comment: Calling `equals` on `Date` objects actually checks the contained time stamp, not just the reference... See the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

Comment: @Baz that is why I have written behavior for `Object.equals`. And please note, that timestamp includes mins, secs, msecs

Comment: `Object.equals` doesn't apply here, but yes, you are right about the time of day.

Comment: @Baz added description for `Date.equals` to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you create dates. If you get them from a DatePicker or parse a String which does not include hours and minutes, then you can use:

```
patient.getBirthday().getTime() == birthday.getTime();
```

If your dates include hours and minutes, you can do:

```
int day = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
boolean sameDate = patient.getBirthday().getTime()/day == birthday.getTime()/day;
```